# Identify the caterpillars

Tags: species-identification, entomology

These are the two caterpillar I found at Taipei, Taiwan. Can anybody help me identify the species. The first caterpillar is about 6-7 cm long and the other one 10-12 cm. Thanks in advance!

[image: cat1]

[image: cat2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not easy - for the first one I am sure that is a caterpillar from order [Orgyia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgyia) and the family [Erebidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erebidae), but since there is a vast number of different caterpillars on all continents, I am not sure which one it is exactly.
If you look at this image (from [here](http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/sci/bio/life/insecta/lepidoptera/ditrysia/noctuoidea/erebidae/lymantriinae/orgyia/)), you will see a striking resemblance:

[image]

A lot more information on these moths can be found [here](http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/sci/bio/life/insecta/lepidoptera/ditrysia/noctuoidea/erebidae/lymantriinae/orgyia/).

The second one is most likely Trabala vishnou ssp. guttata, see the image (from [here](https://breedingbutterflies.com/trabala-vishnou/)) for comparision:

[image]

There seems to be very little information available, some on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabala_vishnou).